# Java MySQL null resultset

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to write a small java application that returns the details for an employee. Here's my Employee class.

```
public class Employees {

private int id;
private Date dateofBirth;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private enum gender{
    M, F;
}
private gender employeeGender;
private Date dateHired;

public String getEmployeeGender() {
    return this.employeeGender.name();
}

public void setEmployeeGender(String employeeGender) {
    this.employeeGender = gender.valueOf(employeeGender);
}

/*Getters, setters omitted*/
```

Here's my DAO class

```
public class EmployeeDao {

final String TABLE_EMPLOYEES = "employees";
final String COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_ID = "emp_no";
final String COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_DOB = "birth_date";
final String COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
final String COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
final String COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_GENDER = "gender";
final String COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_HIRE_DATE = "hire_date";

final String QUERY_EMPLOYEES = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_ID + " = ?";

public Employees getEmployeeDetails(int employeeId) {
    Employees employee = new Employees();
    try (DbConnection dbConnection = new DbConnection();
         Connection databaseConnection = dbConnection.getConn();
         PreparedStatement selectFromEmployees = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(QUERY_EMPLOYEES)) {
        selectFromEmployees.setInt(1, employeeId);
        try (ResultSet result = selectFromEmployees.executeQuery()) {

            if (result.next() == false) {
                System.out.println("Empty Resultset");
            }
            while (result.next()) {
                employee.setId(result.getInt(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_ID));
                employee.setFirstName(result.getString(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_FIRST_NAME));
                employee.setLastName(result.getString(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_LAST_NAME));
                employee.setDateofBirth(result.getDate(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_DOB));
                employee.setEmployeeGender(result.getString(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_GENDER));
                employee.setDateHired(result.getDate(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_HIRE_DATE));
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return employee;
}
```

}

But when I try to run the app in main method like this, I get an output with null values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EmployeeDao employeeDao = new EmployeeDao();
    Employees employees = employeeDao.getEmployeeDetails(39256);
    System.out.println(employees.getId() + " \n" + employees.getFirstName() + " \n" + employees.getLastName() + " \n" + employees.getDateofBirth() + " \n" + employees.getDateHired());
}
```

This is the output.
[image]

This is how the corresponding row looks like in the database
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should not call `next` twice, since it will move the cursor forward again. Try this:

```
if (result.next() == false) {
    System.out.println("Empty Resultset");
} else {
    employee.setId(result.getInt(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_ID));
    employee.setFirstName(result.getString(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_FIRST_NAME));
    employee.setLastName(result.getString(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_LAST_NAME));
    employee.setDateofBirth(result.getDate(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_DOB));
    employee.setEmployeeGender(result.getString(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_GENDER));
    employee.setDateHired(result.getDate(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_HIRE_DATE));
}
```

Comment: @RoshanUpreti No problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Calling `ResultSet#next` moves the cursor forward a row, so your `if` condition loses the first row. Since you know your query can return at most one row, you don't need the `while` loop at all, however:

```
public Employees getEmployeeDetails(int employeeId) throws SQLException {
    Employees employee = null;
    try (DbConnection dbConnection = new DbConnection();
         Connection databaseConnection = dbConnection.getConn();
         PreparedStatement selectFromEmployees = 
            databaseConnection.prepareStatement(QUERY_EMPLOYEES)) {

        selectFromEmployees.setInt(1, employeeId);
        try (ResultSet result = selectFromEmployees.executeQuery()) {

            if (result.next()) {
                employee = new Employees();
                employee.setId(result.getInt(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_ID));
                employee.setFirstName(result.getString(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_FIRST_NAME));
                employee.setLastName(result.getString(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_LAST_NAME));
                employee.setDateofBirth(result.getDate(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_DOB));
                employee.setEmployeeGender(result.getString(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_GENDER));
                employee.setDateHired(result.getDate(COLUMN_EMPLOYEES_HIRE_DATE));
            }
        }
    }
    return employee;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It really helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

No need to add extra `result.next()` comparison.

```
if (result.next() == false) {
 System.out.println("Empty Resultset");
}
while (result.next()){

}
```

while will execute only if there are any rows.

Check the size of list generated before using to check if it contains value or not.